# @MetaMask / detect-provider: handle Accounts Changed

Tags: metamask

I'm using @metamask/detect-provider, when I use the second account of my metamask wallet, this second account is not considered in execution. This is the first account that is always taken in the execution

Comment: Can you show us what you have done? I use the onAccountChange event from the provider to switch accounts. It's working fine.

Comment: Please, Can you show me an example of using onAccountChange?

Comment: my code is below